# Weird ThreadAbortException in custom IOptionsFactory<OpenIdConnectOptions> when debugging only?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, exception, async-await

My class is the following:

```
public class OpenIdConnectOptionsFactory : IOptionsFactory<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>> _setups;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>> _postConfigures;
    private readonly ITenantRepository _tenantRepository;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidateOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>> _validations;

    public OpenIdConnectOptionsFactory(IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>> setups,
        IEnumerable<IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>> postConfigures,
        ITenantRepository tenantRepository)
        : this(setups, postConfigures, tenantRepository, validations: null)
    {
    }

    public OpenIdConnectOptionsFactory(IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>> setups,
        IEnumerable<IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>> postConfigures,
        ITenantRepository tenantRepository,
        IEnumerable<IValidateOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>> validations)
    {
        _setups = setups;
        _postConfigures = postConfigures;
        _tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
        _validations = validations;
    }

    public OpenIdConnectOptions Create(string name)
    {
        // Exception originates from inside this method
        // When this method is changed to use a synchronous counter-part, it works, 
        // but I'm not sure why. The error only happens when debugging 
        // and specifically when you step by step through the code.
        // Debugger does not even hit this method signature, when the 
        // exception originates from a call from inside here.
        var tenant = _tenantRepository.FindAsync(name).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        OpenIdConnectOptions options = new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            // Populate options
        };

        foreach (IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions> setup in _setups)
        {
            if (setup is IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions> namedSetup)
            {
                namedSetup.Configure(name, options);
            }
            else if (name == Options.DefaultName)
            {
                setup.Configure(options);
            }
        }

        foreach (IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions> post in _postConfigures)
        {
            post.PostConfigure(name, options);
        }

        if (_validations != null)
        {
            var failures = new List<string>();
            foreach (IValidateOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions> validate in _validations)
            {
                ValidateOptionsResult result = validate.Validate(name, options);
                if (result != null && result.Failed)
                {
                    failures.AddRange(result.Failures);
                }
            }

            if (failures.Count > 0)
            {
                throw new OptionsValidationException(name, typeof(OpenIdConnectOptions), failures);
            }
        }

        return options;
    }
}
```

and I also have a custom `IOptonsMonitorCache<OpenIdConnectOptions>`:

```
public class OpenIdConnectOptionsCache : IOptionsMonitorCache<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public OpenIdConnectOptionsCache(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
       // Clear me up
    }

    public OpenIdConnectOptions GetOrAdd(string name, Func<OpenIdConnectOptions> createOptions)
    {
        if (createOptions is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(createOptions));
        }

        name ??= Options.DefaultName;
        Lazy<OpenIdConnectOptions> value;

        value = _memoryCache.GetOrCreate(name, cache =>
        {
            var item = new Lazy<OpenIdConnectOptions>(createOptions);
            cache.Value = item;
            cache.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            return item;
        });

        // When you specifically step by step in the debugger to this line, 
        // and you execute it, the ThreadAbort exception fires.
        // If you opt not to go step-through step, i.e you skip this method's execution,
        // no such error appears.
        return value.Value;
    }

    public bool TryAdd(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        }

        if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(name, out _))
        {
            _memoryCache.Set(name, new Lazy<OpenIdConnectOptions>(options));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool TryRemove(string name)
    {
        _memoryCache.TryGetValue(name, out Lazy<OpenIdConnectOptions> value);

        if (value != null)
        {
            _memoryCache.Remove(name);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

So far, no such error has been thrown in any way, shape or form when not debugging, but if I'm debugging, and I specifically hold the debugger over the `value.Value` line of my code and fire it, the exception happens.

Is this a bug to be reported to Microsoft, or what exactly is going on here?

Exact exception thrown:

```
ThreadAbortException: System error.
Repository<T>.Find(string name) in Repository.cs, line 55
    }
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>.Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
....
```

Comment: Well... According to your stack trace the exception is being raised in `Repository` class... Likely due to you using GetAwaiter() + GetResult() instead of awaiting

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yeah but it doesn't happen when debugging is turned off, hence the question - what's really going on here?

Comment: Because there is a lot of voodoo magic that goes on behind the scenes to support debugging and pausing threads and such. Awaiters have special handling in debugger as well. When misusing via GetAwaiter+GetResult you must be hitting a "bug" in the debugger

Comment: Are you sure you're using asp.net core and not asp.net?

Comment: @KevinGosse of course! ASP Net Core 3.1